# Pass a php variable from js to php and return content issue

Tags: javascript, php

I try to pass a $_GET variable from js to php and return the content from php.
I tried out the 
1`st page:
PHP CODE

```
<?php $page = $_GET[url];?>
```

JS CODE

```
var foo = '<?php echo $page ?>';
$.post('fbapp.php', {url: 'foo'});
$("#continut").load('fbapp.php', function () {
    $('.loader').fadeOut();
});
```

But every time the sended variable is empty and when i try to debug 
the $_POST variable from the fbapp.php file i get:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Have any ideea ?

Comment: why are you using post on js and get on php? they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the string `'foo'` when you mean to be using the JavaScript variable `foo`.

```
$.post('fbapp.php', {url: foo});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php $page = $_GET['url'];?>

var foo = '<?php echo $page ?>';

$.post('fbapp.php', 
    {
        url: foo
    }
);

$("#continut").load('fbapp.php', function () {
    $('.loader').fadeOut();
});
```

Note: Send `foo` as variable not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the POST request and looking for variable in GET array. Try to use $_POST["url"]

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong here,

1. GET variable

   ```
   <?php $page = $_GET['url'];//Use quotes?>
   ```
2. Use js variable proper

   ```
   $.post('fbapp.php', {url: foo}); // here 'foo' will be string
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Change first line to

```
<?php $page = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';?>
```

and use var instead of string in

```
var foo = '<?php echo $page ?>';
$.post('fbapp.php', {url: foo});
$("#continut").load('fbapp.php', function () {
    $('.loader').fadeOut();
});
```